# floor( 1.0f ) bugged?

Tags: c++

I just displayed the value for floor( 1.0f ) and surprisingly, it's 0.

Anyone knows about that? Is there a fix in libc expected any time soon?

I've been looking at libc::floor.s but it's a bit dodgy and 1) I don't want to break my other existing code and 2) don't have time for that so I'll add an epsilon at the moment (but that defeats the purpose of floor)...

Thanks for posting any fix or idea on how to bypass the issue.

Comment: Post your complete, working sketch that show your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a generic computer problem (aka, internal floating point representation), not related to any platform in particular.

Comment: @Patapom Please expand on your question. Please also your code so far. Only then will people consider to re-open the question.

Comment: It's _not_ a generic computer problem : this is the way floating-point values are handled by the libc and it can be fixed directly in libc.
As far as I know, arduino boards don't have FPUs so it's a software problem and on my board floor( 1.0 ) returns 0.0...

Answer (score 5):

I ran this sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(floor(1.0f));
}
```

It outputs "1.0"

Comment: What can I say more? I'm using Arduino v1.6.19 and the libc attached to that version, I wrote the exact same code as you did and it displays 0.0...

Comment: The first thing is to update to the last Arduino IDE 1.8.5. Second ... post your sketch!!! It can be the most trivial thing, but no sketch, no help.

Comment: Okay okay thanks! I'm new there... :D
(anyway, my sketch is the same as yours) (I'll update my version)